# How to make css animation to start within a container?

Tags: javascript, html, css

[image]

Circle 1 represents: The animation where the code is starting from
Circle 2 is the point where I want the code to start. 
How can this be done?

I'm using keyframes for animation.

Code:

```
p {   animation-duration: 3s;   animation-name: slidein; }

@keyframes slidein {   from {
    margin-left: 100%;
    width: 300%;    }

  to {
    margin-left: 0%;
    width: 100%;   } }
```

Comment: position the absolute positioned child relative to parent.

Comment: Could you please elaborate? I'm new to UI/UX. Thanks in advance

Comment: What exactly is the desired behavior? Do you want the <p> will be position where your circle2 is located?

Comment: I want the contents within the white-box to start emerging from the right-most edge of the white-box only. Now, they are entering from the edge of the screen. Please let me know if this can be done using CSS

Answer (score 0):

**check the below snippet:**

```js
var dur;

function animate(){
    $('.progress').stop();
    $('.progress').animate({width: '100%'},
    {
     duration: dur,
      easing: 'linear',
     queue: false,
      done: function(){
       $(this).css({width: '0%'});
      }
    })
};

$('.slow').click(function(){
    dur = 5 * 1000;
    animate();
});

$('.fast').click(function(){
   dur = 0.5 * 1000;
   animate();
});
```

```css
.progress {
  width: 0%;
  padding:10px;
  background:red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button class="fast">fast</button>
<button class="slow">slow</button>

<div class="progress"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Put you animated container inside another container. Now the location is relative to the outside container and not the browser window.